# Ending of Bloody Monday season 3

Tags: bloody-monday

I started reading this series around 5 years ago. Finally finished it because the last chapter was finally translated, so I might have forgotten some things along the way.

Can someone explain to me the ending? My guess is that it was Maya in disguised delivering the flowers. The delivery lady also states the bouquet was from a "friend". If it is really Maya's gift, that makes me wonder is it actually a gift or perhaps a bomb / something malicious?

What is the intent and purpose of the flowers?

Comment: @user1306322 The name of this series is called Bloody Monday Last Season. For some reason, this site doesn't let me use the correct tag.

Comment: This is a series and tags usually include all seasons of a series, so you can use this tag.

Comment: @user1306322 I don't think we should change the title though. This is a manga and BM:LS is the exact name of it. It doesn't really make sense to call this season 3 when I can put the exact name `Last Season` in the title, right?

Comment: Do whatever you want, man. Season 3 is an alternative title that people recognize, it's descriptive and not as ambiguous as "Last Season". But it's your post and you can title it whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this question and just finished the manga myself.

Maya was plotting a revenge against Falcon and Otoya by hiding a gun inside the flower basket.

As you recall during the final moments before the Storyteller's death, Maya's background detailing her childhood days training to be an agent took place. She was contemplating about life after that mission - maybe a housewife etc.

However, looking at the happy faces of the 2 girls she was about to shoot, she could not bear to pull the trigger and left it as it is while leaving behind a relieved Kanou, who saw the letter bidding farewell from Maya.

Hope this clarifies. When I first saw Maya during the wedding, I expected the worst but glad to see a happy ending =)